# pandas.plot and pyplot.save_fig create different sized PNGs for same figsize

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

When I call the same function that uses pandas.plot with the same figsize, I get different sized PNG files.  The width is same but the height in pixels changes. I suspect that the length of the x-axis labels changes the height.I have not yet tried directly calling the matplotlib functions.

I have also tried `plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (7,4)`. The problem does not appear to be in how figsize is set. My `print_fig_info` always produces the desire values.

```
# Primitive way that confirmed that the figure size does not change
def print_fig_info(label=""):
    print(label,str(plt.gcf().get_size_inches()))

def my_plot(df):
    global c
    print_fig_info("Before plot")
    df.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(7,4))
    print_fig_info("After  plot")

    # want to make output files unique
    c += 1
    plt.savefig("output"+str(c), bbox_inches='tight', dpi='figure')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your call to `savefig` you explicitely ask matplotlib to change the figsize to the minimal size that still fits all the elements in via `bbox_inches='tight'`. 
Or in other words, `bbox_inches='tight'` is especially designed for changing the figure size to the minimum bounding box, and matplotlib is therefore doing what it's being asked for.

Solution: Don't use `bbox_inches='tight'`.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, to get a _tight_ fit, `savefig, bbox='tight'` will either tighten or _expand_ the figure region depending on the need.

Comment: To get labels that extend outside of the initial figure size, I could attempt to use something like:  

`from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox`  
`plt.savefig('test.png',bbox_inches=Bbox.from_extents(0,-2,8,7))`  
  
Need to consider if it is worth the effort.

Comment: If you're aiming at producing figures of the same size and need to make sure the content fits into the given figure size, you can use `plt.tight_layout()` prior to saving.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. I was unaware of the [tight_layout API](http://matplotlib.org/api/tight_layout_api.html). Thank you for helping with more than just the immediate question.